# In SQL Server, is there a performance hit on 200+ columns in a table, or better way to manage it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have a large form, with over 200 questions. Is there an issue with storing all these in a single table? Is there a better way?

Would it be better to have another table that holds values, like QuestionID, QuestionAnswer?

It would certainly be easier to keep it in one table, so just looking for direction to prevent regret later on :)

Comment: I don't think a reasonable answer can be given based on the information here. How much data for each question? How much data for each answer? Are there multiple answers per question?

Comment: What if you have to add or remove questions on the form in the future?  You'll have to change the table structure also to match if you use one column per question.

Comment: Why oh why would you want to put a question as a column, given that you have 200+ questions ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Well I ultimately want to handle it in the best manner, which is why I asked the question. The comments in one of the answers below helped me greatly, about several columns for the different datatypes.

Answer (score 6):

The standard answer is "It depends on your use case and requirements..."

However, I can't think of a single use case where it makes sense to have one column per answer for 200 answers from a design perspective.

I can think of many cases where a short-sighted designer would think that was "easier" and "faster".  It's not.

Comment: +1. I can not come up with any idea why anyone would want to store a quastionaire in this form - it is an abheration of the relational model to start with. Performance would be ok, but this is NOT how a relational database should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that Change Will always Happen and maintainability:

It's better to change rows than columns - because changing data in rows is easy - but modifying table structure could become heavy and difficult.

So I would go the QuestionID, QuestionAnswer route.

---

For display purposes, you can always use the `PIVOT` function.

`PIVOT` can take data that looks like:

```
|AnswererID|Question      |Answer         |
===========================================
|1         |HowOldAreYou  |150 years      |
|2         |HowOldAreYou  |50 years       |
|1         |WhereDoYouLive|Florida        |
|2         |WhereDoYouLive|NewYork        |
```

And Transform it to look like this:

```
|AnswererID|HowOldAreYou|WhereDoYouLive|
========================================
|1         |150 years   |Florida       |
|2         |50 years    |NewYork       |
```

You can read more about `PIVOT` here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you saying that your answer implied you were showing "post pivot".  Fine.  Then also put in an example of pre-pivot because just showing the wrong thing is not clear.  (And yes I got that from the start)

Comment: What about when dealing with datatypes? If one of the questions is a date, and the form control used for it has the date datatype? Does it need to be converted to a string on insert, and converted back to a date prior to update when loading into update form?

Comment: @user1447679 - you have two choices -- cast for non-string types or have multiple columns in the answer table for the different types.  I've done both -- I think the multiple columns is probably better -- less run time cast errors.

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky - I don't think you want the full text of the question in the answer table... should be just an id -- I assume this was to make the example easier to understand.

Comment: @Hogan - correct - it's just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @user1447679 Correct. You would need to cast. You would add another column called `AnswerType` so you can standardize the conversions. Another way to do this is to add `AnswerType` column and then Have multiple columns in that table for every Type(nvarchar, datetime, etc.) that you want to support - but that might be overkill.

Comment: Thank you all very much. I'm going to try this!